# CentOS 6.9 : Remove MySQL and Reinstall another version

Tags: mysql, centos6, installation, yum, version-control

My server is on `CentOS 6.9`, I'm using `yum` to install packages.

**My problem :** I'm trying to install `mysql` service using this command :

```
sudo yum install mysql-server
```

The `yum` loads an incompatible version `mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64`, It should be **.el6** not **.el7**.

So, my question is : How to delete the `.el7` package, and install the `.el6` mysql version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the repo to point to el6 instead of el7. Please review the mysql yum repo instructions: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/

After the repo is configured correctly then you can just do yum install and it should pick up the right one. Run `yum repolist all` to see what you have for mysql.